# Is there a function in C++ to determine if a specific certain folder in a given directory exists or not?

Tags: c++, file, directory

Is there any simple such function in C++? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: What have you tried to figure this out yourself? Did you try at least a Google search or a search of this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Boost's filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).  Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::filesystem::path p("/path/to/directory");

    if (exists(p))
    {
        std::cout << p << " exists!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that Boost filesystem is not header-only and requires library linking.